# Is the interval $(-\infty,0]$ open, closed, or neither?

Tags: general-topology

Consider the set
\begin{equation}
A=(-\infty,0]
\end{equation}
Is this set open, closed, or neither?

---

Let's check. First, note that its complement, $A^\mathsf{c}=(0,\infty)$, is open, which implies that $A$ is closed. However, $A$ appears to be open on the left. I am a bit embarrassed to say I'm not sure whether it is closed or half-open.

Thanks!

Comment: It is closed — as long as you work in $\mathbf R$: $-\infty\notin \mathbf R$. It is *not* in $\overline{\mathbf R}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's closed. Your check is correct. There is potentially conflicting terminology with the words open and closed: on the one hand, the words make sense for parts in any topological space. On the other hand, they can be used to qualify the bounds of an interval. At $\pm \infty$, the open symbol is always used, it's not relevant. So the status of the interval depends only on what happens at the other bound. Note that the interval $(-\infty, +\infty)$ is of course open and closed.

Comment: As noted by others, as long as the topological space you are considering is $\mathbb R$ with its usual topology...

Answer (score 2):

it is closed as a set (though neither, as an interval). A closed set does not mean the same as a closed interval: The latter simply means that the interval contains both endpoints.

For that matter as EthanAlvaree pointed out in a comment, the answer may depend on the topological space under consideration. It seems it is the reals (so then my answer above applies), indeed if the complement of $A$ is $(0,\infty)$ as you stated then it is understood that the whole space is $A$ union its complement, that is $(-\infty,0]\cup(0,\infty)=(-\infty,\infty)$.

But, if the space is a compactification of the reals e.g. something like $[-\infty,\infty]$ then the set $A$ is not closed.

On the other hand if the whole space is $A$ itself, then $A$ is both open and closed. (Alternatively, this also happens if the whole space is the reals, but with the discrete topology.)

Well, yes if you do not make a difference between a closed set and a closed interval (except that a set need not be an interval), then this would be indeed confusing. But I think the accepted terminology regarding intervals is more specific than treating them as simply sets in a topological space. You could talk about intervals any time you have a linear order, even if you have no topology, although you could use intervals to define the so-called order topology ... but you may consider an entirely different topology on your ordered set, and that would not affect the meaning of the terms open, closed, and half-open, as applied to intervals.

Comment: If end points exist… For me, the only difference between a closed set and a closed interval is the former is not (necessarily) an interval.

Comment: the terminology closed/open is different, when applied to [intervals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_%28mathematics%29) (in any linear order), than when applied to sets (in any topological space). There is room for confusion, in particular when the order is not dense, e.g. the integers. Then $(0,4)$ is open, but it is the same as $[1,3]$ which is closed. Also, $(0,4)$ is closed (even using the interval terminology) since it contains its minimum and its maximum. Also, the usual topology of the integers is discrete so any set is both open and closed.

Comment: I'm sorry, I never heard of that. I don't think it is an international convention. The ambiguity is essentially an ambiguity about the topology.

Comment: it may not be an international convention, but it is a mathematical convention that I have seen in the past (but did not invent), and that makes sense to me, so I tried to convey its meaning in my answer. I think one could make a point that when talking about intervals, topology need not be (formally) involved at all, yet the words closed and open may apply.

Comment: Thank you for the very enlightening answer, Mirko!

Answer (score 0):

To determine if $A$ is open, we need to examine if every $x \in A$ has some $\varepsilon > 0$ neighborhood around $x$ completely contained in $A$. To this end, think about any $\varepsilon$ neighborhood centered around $x=0$, and you can deduce whether $A$ is open from there.

Answer (score 0):

It is closed as the preimage under a continous function of the closed set $[0,1]$
$$
(e^x)^{-1}([0,1])
$$